# Large Data transfer using AWS Lambda and AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

We have to create a large zip outputstream (500 MB - 1 GB max file size) using AWS Lambda (Java) and transfer it to S3. I am facing an issue here:

a. Connection timeout as the file is large

If the zip file is small, then it is working fine.

When I checked, it seems like multi-part upload might help. I am yet to try it, but wanted to know if there is a better option.

1. Does file transfer from AWS Lambda to S3 happens over Internet? Is there any way where I can use AWS optimized network since I do not have any need to use data from outside AWS network (the zip data is created within Lambda only). Will that help in faster data transfer?
2. The other option is to use multi part upload using Java (since we are a Java shop).

I understand that AWS Lambda has an execution timeout of 15 minutes. So if the data transfer takes long time, instead of a connection timeout, we might hit Lambda execution timeout. That is also not acceptable. So a fast data transfer would really help. The processing is trivial otherwise - I have to keep the Lambda running only because the data transfer takes long time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not writing the file directly to S3? See sample here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-java

Comment: "AWS Lambda" is not a file storage service. You need to analyze what you're Lambda function is doing.

Comment: From where is the Lambda function obtaining the data that it is uploading?

Comment: Lambda is getting the data from another S3 bucket. The lambda has to encrypt (custom encryption logic) the large file and keep it at another bucket. That is why the data need not leave the AWS network.

Comment: The AWS lambda is completing the encryption logic in less than 20 seconds. It is keeping the encrypted file in memory as a bytearrayoutputstream. I then obtain a bytearrayinputstream from it before trying to write to S3. That is where I get the timeout

Comment: @Sharuzzaman Thanks, willl try this and let you know. But I guess this may not help as the time is lost in data transfer of large object. But I have to test this, thanks for the suggestion. It will help to save memory when compared to my current logic.

Comment: @Jamie I am using Lambda to encrypt the data, not for storage. S3 is used for storage

Comment: @Sharuzzaman Tried it, it helped in saving RAM (earlier I was writing to RAM before sending it to S3). But the issue is not resolved. Still gets timeout on data transfer.

Comment: So we can deduce that Lambda takes a longer time than 15 minutes to write the data to S3 due to the size. At this stage, the next option is to take your code to other service that doesn't have time limit. You can use AWS CodeBuild to launch an instance to perform the encryption, and it will terminate once the copy to S3 complete. Another option is to put your code in container, and call it using Fargate. Fargate can launch or terminate a container on demand

Comment: Thanks for the help. Let me try.. Bit of work involved, need to do some R&D. :-)

Comment: Just curious. Lambda says that it has a payload limit of 6MB per request. Is this applicable when lambda reads large files from S3? It is usually applicable when you upload data from client browser, but not sure if this applicable for S3 too.

Comment: please see this https://theburningmonk.com/2020/04/hit-the-6mb-lambda-payload-limit-heres-what-you-can-do/